# VPC0820 Li-Ion Capacitor how to understand the 97% Self Discharge (V) parameter

Tags: capacitor, lithium-ion, discharge, supercapacitor

Does anyone know what does the self-discharge parameter mean? I know what `self-discharge` is, but what does `over 97%` mean?

[image]

Comment: There is a reference to follow for more information. (It should probably read IEC not ICE, if you are having search problems) It probably means the cap retains 97% of the original voltage under the applied conditions.

Comment: @user16324 interesting what those conditions are